# Clickable options available per condition

Tags: conditional-statements, clickable, dialogflow-cx

I'm building an agent in Dialogflow CX, and I want a yes/no clickable option to pop up when a specific condition is met. More specifically, if the user chooses they want an order for delivery, I want follow up and ask if they want to use a pre-existing address (with yes/no clickable options). However, if the user says they want to place a return, I don't want the clickable option.

I know how to use conditionals to make this happen without the button option, but I don't know how integrate the conditional with the buttons. Also, everytime I try to do this using custom payloads, I just end up seeing the custom payload code in the agent response.